# How to run tests by category in Gradle using command line?

Tags: gradle, junit, automated-tests

I have several tests and each of them is marked with one or more categories listed below

```
@Category(SmokeTest.class)
@Category(RegressionTest.class)
@Category(StressTest.class)
```

How can I run tests a specific category?
For example what I have to write in command line to run tests marked category "SmokeTest"?

Answer (score 3):

In `build.gradle` i have to add

```
test {
    useJUnit() {
        if (project.hasProperty("cat"))
            includeCategories "com.path.to.categories.interfaces.folder.$cat"
    }
}
```

And then enter the following command in terminal

```
./gradlew clean test -Pcat=SmokeTest
```

Answer (score 0):

please see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_grouping

```
test {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryA'
        excludeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryB'
    }
}
```